# executing the bash on the amazon server with a error [Error: spawn EACCES], the bash is in right path

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, amazon-web-services

I am using the gith to build a webhook server on the amazon server to automate the deployment. When I updated my repository, the gith server can receive the update, then I want to execute the bash.
The bash file is on the path of /home/ubuntu/node/githook/hook.sh, `console.log(__dirname+'/hook.sh');` output the right path, but when using the execFile to execute the path, it gave a error

error `{ [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }`

The code is above, but don't know why executing the code gave me such error.

```
var gith = require('gith').create( 8080 );
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
gith({
    repo: 'heroku/node-js-sample'
}).on( 'all', function( payload ) {
    if( payload.branch === 'master' )
    {
        //console.log('all',payload ); 
        console.log(__dirname+'/hook.sh');
        execFile(__dirname+'/hook.sh', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                    // Log success in some manner
            if(error) console.log("error",error);
            else console.log( 'exec complete',stdout );
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: Is hook.sh executable? If not make it with `chmod +x hook.sh`

Comment: Thanks, this is true. I am new to linux, so I don't know to give the permission to bash. can you answer it, so I can approve your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your bash script executable. Use this :

```
chmod +x hook.sh
```